# How to create a new Docker image from a container without an image

Tags: docker

I have a running container but I deleted the original image it was based off and I thought by using `docker commit <container-name>` I could create a new image from my running container.

But I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to get digest sha256:19d9e777d6b04fa62fcaac1a98dcdb11ec94e8ffb2c3c4d3ace2d81b210fc6b4: open /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/19d9e777d6b04fa62fcaac1a98dcdb11ec94e8ffb2c3c4d3ace2d81b210fc6b4: no such file or directory
```

I cannot redownload the original image I deleted because it was custom. I just want to create a new image from a container which is running already. What can I do?

Comment: You should be able to check out the original image from source control and `docker build` it again.  `docker rmi` won't usually let you delete an image if there's a running container based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing can be done. Its like you deleted the executable of which an instance is running in memory. Now the original executable can't be created from that. Same goes here.

Most probably that lost image won't be a base image unless that is the case in reality, so try to find the docker file / commands that helped created that custom image and try to recreate that. and Don't forget to push it some registry this time.

Comment: I was guessing this might be the case. Is it not possible to change the image of a container to use another image? This image that I lost was original based of `ubuntu:20.04`, is it still not possible to switch over to that one?

Comment: @Erdss4 you seems to be mixing up. Container is running instance of Image. Once created it cannot point to another image. Now Image itself can either be part of changes from image or is a base image. In your case, it seems your original image was ubuntu then download that image again simply

Answer (score 0):

Do u have the dockerfile u built the image ? if so you can try to rebuild it again and then use that image to create containers from that again..
make sure to push to a registry